# What is the description of this set means

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$
S=\{a\leq t\leq b : f(s)<0 , 0\leq s<t\}
$$

what is the relationship between
t and s
Appreciate for answering

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the notation and suspect this must be read as: $$\{t\in[a,b]\mid\text{function }f\text{ is negative on interval }[0,t)\}$$This clears out the $s$.

Another way is:$$\{t\in[a,b]\mid\forall s\in[0,t)\;[f(s)<0]\}$$where the $s$ only turns up as *bound* variable.

Especially the fact that this is not clear in the original notation bothers me.